# z-index causes issues with buttons nearby...but I need it

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've got a div container of a menu, simple example:

```
          <div class="nav-container">
            <div id="corp-crumb">
                <ul class="vertlist" id="ulTop">
                    <li class="crumblink submenu"><a id="createNewLink" href="#" title="Create New" class="crumblink">Create New</a>
                         <ul>
                            <li><a href="/Views/Company/Create.aspx" title="Company">Company</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/Views/Contact/Create.aspx" title="Contact">Contact</a></li>
                             <li><a href="/Views/Corporate/Create.aspx" title="Corporate Group">Corp. Group</a></li>
                             <li><a href="/Views/Issue/Create.aspx" title="Issue">Issue</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/Views/Program/Create.aspx" title="Program">Program</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/Views/Project/Create.aspx" title="Project">Project</a></li>
                            <li><a href="/Views/SubProject/Create.aspx" title="Sub Project">Sub Project</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                 </ul>
             </div>
          </div>
```

This menu is at the top of all my pages, when the user scrolls the page I ensure that the menu is still visible via jquery, something to the effect of:

```
            var nav = $('.nav-container');
            var cc = $("#corp-crumb");

            $(window).scroll(function () {
                marginTop = ($(document).scrollTop() - scroll) + marginTop;
                scroll = $(document).scrollTop();
                if ($(this).scrollTop() > 50) {
                    nav.addClass("f-nav");
                    cc.addClass("addShadow");
                } else {
                    nav.removeClass("f-nav");
                    cc.removeClass("addShadow");
                }
            });
```

This basically says if the user scrolls add the class "f-nav" to the div nav, which is the `nav-container` shown above.  The class f-nav has the following definition:

```
.f-nav {
     z-index: 9999; 
     position: fixed; 
     left: 10px; 
     top: 0; 
     width: 100%;
} /* this make our menu fixed top */
```

If the user scrolls back to the top we remove this class, as shown in the jquery else condition.  This works fine...however the minute someone moves close to say some buttons on my page the z-index is causing the user not to be able to click the buttons, say for instance in this screen shot:

[image]

In chrome developer tools If I uncheck the z-index I can now click a button however my menu is sent behind the page as shown:

[image]

Is there some magical CSS available so that this doesnt happen?  Im not sure why it is causing this issue...

Comment: Can you make a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) showing the issue?

Comment: If you put some padding at the top of your content div, the elements wouldn't be able to scroll underneath. Not a fix, but it would avoid the problem.

Comment: @jstaab can you please clarify, padding to which content, which div?

Comment: Yeah, I'm talking about the div that has the scrollable content (it looks like it ends at the first border outside the grayish area). If you just added a bit of padding there, above the buttons, they wouldn't be able to scroll the buttons to the top.

Comment: @jstaab - I dont think that will work, remember the menu follows you as you scroll.  So if I put padding I assume you mean on the menu it can still and will go over the buttons as long as I scroll down.  Does that make sense?

Comment: In addition- adding padding-bottom: 10px for instance, has no effect.  Because remember even if you have padding you can eventually scroll over the buttons.

Comment: I mean add padding-top to the div that gets hidden. Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/DhaT5/

Comment: Yes this will work per your fiddle, however I do not want to have padding at the top of my body container.  I  am using a master page, on my master page I have a header (the navigation bar), a body container, and a footer.  I can easily add padding-top to the body container in a style sheet, but that shift my body down and I don't want to do that.

Comment: @JonH - please make a playground page which is the same

Comment: Why do you both use `position: fixed` and the jQuery code? btw. share a Fiddle please!

Comment: Fiddle would be best. But based on the pictures, it may be caused by clicking on part of the semi-transparent shadow layer instead of the underlying button. Removing the shadow and replacing it with a more obvious division may be the solution (e.g. http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/)

Comment: If you really want people to help you, and can not make a fiddle demonstrating the issue, at least you should include all the relevant code here. *specifically*, you should post the CSS for #corp-crumb .nav-container and .addShadow   I think that the clue is the later

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say your navigation is taking more height then it should. There is a transparent space beneath it covering up the other buttons. This could be any margin or padding on your navigation links. Since we don't have all code it is hard to tell what exactly goes wrong.

Try adding height to f-nav.

```
.f-nav {
  z-index: 9999; 
  position: fixed; 
  left: 10px; 
  top: 0; 
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px; /* Limit the height */
  overflow: hidden; /* Make sure no content overflows */
}
```

Comment: Ack...this was it, our navigation bar was actually too tall, couldnt notice it due to some of the css / design we had.  This worked thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The div "under" your navigation container div needs a padding on the top to prevent elements to get under your nav div.

```
<div class="nav-container">

     <!--Lots of other elements-->

</div><!--closing the nav-container div-->

<div id='div-under-nav'>
     <!--Your div with the buttons that gets into trouble-->
</div>
```

The above snippet is my assumption of your situation. lets say your nav container is 30px in height, then the first 30px of your div-under-nav is underneath it.

to fix that set this in your CSS

```
#div-under-nav{padding-top: 30px;}
```

Sorry for all the pseudo code but you did not gave me much to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the pictures, it may be caused by clicking on part of the semi-transparent shadow layer (corp-crumb) instead of the underlying button.

You can test if that is the case by replacing the menu shadow with a solid color as [done by others](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top). Or by removing corp-crumb and the js bits that reference it altogether. That way it will be easy to see when one is clicking on the menu shadow layer or the button below it.

Answer (score 0):

you could avoid `.f-nav` to catch click events using : `pointer-events:none;`, it should not affect inside links.

```
.f-nav {
     z-index: 9999; 
     position: fixed; 
     left: 10px; 
     top: 0; 
     width: 100%; 
     pointer-events:none; /* avoid this wrapper to catch click events */
} /* this make our menu fixed top */
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the shadow layer below the menu having the same z-index value causing the buttons stay below it and unreachable, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

hope this will helpful to someone with js ✌️

```
onClick={(e) => e.stopPropagation()}
```